# Why does long PHP script stop without error unless logging?

Tags: php, debugging, logging

I'm witnessing very strange behavior: a long-running PHP script called via AJAX will run for about 30 minutes. However, when I run it without any `error_log()` statements, it stops after about 150 seconds with no error. When I add some `error_log()` statements to track where it's stopping (and why), it completes without a problem.

In other words, it works only when it's being "observed".

Any ideas why this might be happening? Thanks!

Note:
I call both `ignore_user_abort()` and `set_time_limit(0)` in the script.

Comment: and the script would be?

Comment: Hi, and thanks. It processes jpeg image files created by ffmpeg and writes info to a mysql database.

Comment: @ScottyB, the delay may depend on the destination of the log messages. For example, `error_log` writing to local filesystem will be faster than `error_log` writing to network filesystem, or sending the message via mail.